# Hamming distance in XOR decryption

Tags: xor, hamming

I've been working on [cryptopals 1.6](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6), breaking XOR, and have got it working. I found [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8115/repeating-key-xor-and-hamming-distance) that explains why hamming distance works, and after some consideration I believe I'm starting to understand it.

One thing that I stumbled on was key size estimation, step 3. I finally found a write-up:

```
fn score_keysize(keysize, bytes) {
  let block1 = bytes.getblock(size=keysize)
  let block2 = bytes.getblock(offset=keysize, size=keysize)
  let block3 = bytes.getblock(offset=keysize*2, size=keysize)
  let block4 = bytes.getblock(offset=keysize*3, size=keysize)
  let hamming = hamming(a,b) + hamming(b,c) + hamming(c,d)
  return hamming / 3
}
```

And this works. I tried a variant but didn't even get nearly as good results. Almost all of my attempts, with some variance, got a lower score the larger the key became, this included.

```
fn score_keysize(keysize, bytes) {
  let block1 = bytes.getblock(size=keysize)
  let block2 = bytes.getblock(offset=keysize, size=keysize)
  let block3 = bytes.getblock(offset=keysize*2, size=keysize)
  let block4 = bytes.getblock(offset=keysize*3, size=keysize)
  let hamming = hamming(a,b) + hamming(c,d)
  return hamming / 2
}
```

Could someone explain why that's so much worse? Or is it dependent on the text?